# iOS - Change behavior of UIImageView setImage: (custom setter)

Tags: ios

I want to perform additional tasks whenever the image of a UIImageView is set. I'm attempting to define a custom setter method, but having no luck.

h:

`@property (nonatomic, strong, setter = setImage:) UIImage *image;`

m:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    self.image = image;
    // additional tasks here
}
```

This obviously incurs an infinite loop. How do I do this?

Comment: try getting rid of the setter=setImage: and try again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
    self.image = image;
```

do

```
    [super setImage:image];
```

Also, you don't need to specify the setter since that is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you are triggering setter with **`self.image = image;`**

use **`_image = image;`** to avoid that.